# Add sum of all numbers in an array and print the final result

Tags: javascript

please don't kill me right away, because some topics are already here in the forum. I've read and tried a lot. I just don't get any further with my beginner knowledge.

My problem is the following: I have 4 arrays, the length of the arrays can have a different length each time. Now I would like to add the sum of all 4 arrays and get a final result.

I just can't really get any further than I want. Please bear with me and help me.

Here my example :

```
var MyData = '{"M":[{"M":{"MD":995,"PT":1,"TT":17,"D":0,"TID":44,"T":0,"HW":109,"KD":0,"TA":[4,17,77,17010,84,5,6,6,6,5,"xxxx",0,0,128,6,-1,0,34,[],0],"SD":1187,"OD":117,"SA":[1,65,67,194,187,7,8,7,6,6,"yyyy",0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,95,[],0]},"UM":{"PD":0,"TD":0,"L":{"ID":23,"ID":2,"VIS":14,"N":"bbbb","GD":102,"L":17,"W":1429,"D":113,"SPR":9,"Q":[[1647,1,2,5,-1,[[4,40,[114.0]],[5,46,[74.3]],[18,89,[43.6]],[116,34,[42.2]]],-1,-1,0,-1,-1,3,[1,5,3090,[7222,32,5,310,[[312,46,[11.4]],[311,55,[12.8]],[34,72,[19.7]],[30,28,[8.4]]],0]]],[187,2,2,5,-1,[[1,9,[82.4]],[2,86,[86.3]],[112,67,[28.1]],[19,35,[22.0]]],-1,-1,0,-1,-1,3,[2,6,2970,[7127,32,6,3240,[[311,28,[8.5]],[314,67,[18.7]],[32,83,[17.3]],[315,46,[8.0]]],0]]],[14650745,3,2,5,-1,[[3,97,[116.8]],[6,55,[74.8]],[109,42,[24.8]],[116,65,[67.0]]],-1,-1,0,-1,-1,3,[3,6,3590,[77381,32,6,3130,[[313,33,[6.3]],[310,83,[21.1]],[312,61,[13.8]],[311,36,[9.8]]],0]]],[14673,4,2,5,-1,[[7,82,[16.1]],[115,40,[21.0]],[121,87,[215,871.0]],[112,48,[22.4]]],-1,-1,0,-1,-1,3,[4,6,3570,[72077,32,2,2710,[[312,44,[11.0]],[311,52,[12.3]],[313,37,[6.8]],[38,38,[8.8]]],0]]],[14681483230,5,2,0,0,[[21,[5.0]]],1070,-1,0,630006,-1,2],[14649672824,6,2,15,-1,[[808,82,[47.1]],[811,77,[28.1]],[812,50,[20.0]],[815,35,[18.4]],[20018,100,[1.0]],[20016,7,[2060,12.0,2061,12.0,2062,12.0,2063,12.0,2064,12.0,2065,12.0,2066,12.0,2067,12.0,2068,12.0,148,12.0,2069,12.0,149,12.0,2070,12.0,150,12.0,151,12.0,2071,12.0,2072,12.0,2073,12.0,2074,12.0,2075,12.0,2076,12.0,2077,12.0,2078,12.0,2079,12.0,2020,12.0,2021,12.0,2022,12.0,2023,12.0,2024,12.0,2025,12.0,2026,12.0,2027,12.0,2028,12.0,2029,12.0,2030,12.0,2031,12.0,2032,12.0,2033,12.0,2034,12.0,2035,12.0,2036,12.0,2037,12.0,2038,12.0,2039,12.0]]],-1,-1,0,-1,-1,3,[65,6,3440,[]]]],"IDS":[[10021,1023],[10022,1033]],"SIS":[1033,1009,1040,100253],"AE":[[64,[8.0]],[503,[20.0]],[504,[48.0]],[504,[48.0]],[339,[50.0]],[504,[48.0]],[613,[50.0]],[66,[65.0]],[503,[65.0]],[503,[45.0]],[504,[30.0]],[504,[45.0]],[614,[8.0]],[66,[48.0]],[504,[60.0]],[66,[45.0]],[504,[48.0]],[614,[30.0]],[66,[24.0]]]}},"GA":{"L":[[287,30],[216,2224],[215,744],[298,60],[651,76],[650,90],[649,132],[240,50]],"M":[[287,30],[216,2720],[215,3808],[298,60],[651,48],[650,102],[649,125],[648,179],[240,50]],"R":[[287,30],[216,2968],[298,60],[651,76],[650,90],[649,132],[240,50]],"RW":[[215,2358],[216,433]]},"AST":[390,400],"ATT":0,"SM":0}],"O":[{"OID":8344,"DUM":false,"N":"xrr","E":{"BGT":0,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":1644825,"SPT":2,"S1":82,"SC1":144394,"S2":82,"SC2":163,"IS":1},"L":7,"LL":50,"H":3195,"AVZ":180,"CF":3911,"HF":16245,"PRE":13,"SUF":23,"TPX":-1,"MP":459,"R":0,"AID":48,"AR":0,"AN":"drum vv","aee":{"CF":237604,"BGT":7,"BGC1":16825,"BGC2":3012,"BGC3":864,"SPT":23,"S1":2,"SC1":30512,"S2":41,"SC2":164825,"S3":0,"SC3":164825},"RPT":0,"AP":[[0,1007,1062,76,1],[0,1170610,1067,757,4],[0,1211752,1056,755,4],[0,100,1059,72,4],[1,163,710,79,12],[2,16771,809,68,12],[3,2052697,772,504,12]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":1,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OD":1187,"DM":false,"N":"xyz","E":{"BGT":1,"BG1":81264,"BG2":5126,"SPT":1,"S1":82,"S1":16425,"S2":82,"S2":164825,"IS":1},"L":7,"LL":90,"H":6738,"AVP":87345,"CF":4591,"HF":5623,"PRE":13,"SUF":27,"TX":1,"P":8828,"R":0,"AD":88,"AR":7,"AN":"DDR ","aee":{"CF":1878,"BT":2,"BC1":14494,"BG2":1894,"BC3":-1,"SPT":0,"S1":-1,"S1":-1,"S2":-1,"SC2":-1,"S3":-1,"SC3":-1},"RPT":0,"AP":[[0,1417194,675,607,1],[0,2086,795,1180,4],[0,3363161,663,603,4],[0,7164676,769,1179,4],[1,489,490,318,12],[2,208,33,71,12],[3,4347,42,108,12],[4,112,818,61,12]],"VP":[],"A":0,"VF":0,"PF":1,"RD":0,"TI":-1,"RP":-1}]}'

var MyArray = JSON.parse(MyData)

MyArray.M[0].GA.L.forEach(element1 => console.log(element1[1]));
MyArray.M[0].GA.M.forEach(element2 => console.log(element2[1]));
MyArray.M[0].GA.R.forEach(element3 => console.log(element3[1]));
MyArray.M[0].GA.RW.forEach(element4 => console.log(element4[1]));
```

//So I give myself all the values ​​first.

//If I then use the for loop on one of the arrays, I get the output:

```
let sum = 0;

MyArray.M[0].GA.L.forEach(element1 => {
  

const MyArray = [element1[1]];

 for (let i = 0; i < MyArray.length; i++) {
    sum += MyArray[i];
}
console.log(sum); 
  
})
```

//output: 30,2254,2998,3058,3134,3224,3356,3406

The number 3406 is the End Result, how can I print only the End result.

If there is another method to add all 4 arrays together at once, it would help me even more.

If possible an example for an array and an example for all 4 together please

Answer (score 1):

you have to do three things: consolidate all the arrays, get the sum of all values, then print it

first, consolidate

```
const allArrs = [
  ...MyArray.M[0].GA.L,
  ...MyArray.M[0].GA.M,
  ...MyArray.M[0].GA.R,
  ...MyArray.M[0].GA.RW
]
```

then, the array method that would help the most here is [Array.Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
const result = allArrs.reduce((accumulator, currentArray) => {
  accumulator += currentArray[1]
  return accumulator
}, 0)
```

then log the result!

Comment: I didn't think about using `spread` to expand the values into a single large array. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, this type of problem is very well suited for using a *functional programming* approach, where you simplify the problem by morphing it into a series of atomic operations that have no side-effects.

JavaScript does a great job of implementing the core functional programming methods of `map()`, `filter()`, and `reduce()`. For this problem, the only thing you need is `reduce()`.

The code below could be made smaller and more efficient, but it was written to show each individual step.

```js
const data = JSON.parse(rawData);

// subData is now an object whose members are the arrays you care about
const subData = data.M[0].GA;

// turn that into an array of arrays
const myArrays = Object.values(subData);

// now use reduce() to flatten the array of arrays into a single array with just
// the numbers you want to sum
const myNums = myArrays.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val[1]), []);

// finally, reduce() again to sum the values
const sum = myNums.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: With your method I get a result of 9209.

If all 4 are added together, I should come up with about 16000. As with the other examples. Otherwise your method is much shorter for me.

Comment: @Jeffrey I'm a little uncertain about what it is you are trying to sum. With the code above, in the 2nd to last step you end up with a set of 4 arrays. Each element in each of those arrays is itself a two element array. My understanding is that you are only trying to sum the *second* number from those two-number arrays (as evidenced by your use of the specific sub-index `1` in `element1[1]`). If you meant to use both numbers from that 2-element list for your sum, then change `acc.concat(val[1])` to `acc.concat([...val[0], ...val[1]])`.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Simply move `console.log(sum)` outside of the final `})` so it's not inside any loops.

Comment: shaking head,
Thank you very much, I could now get angry to no end.

So problem 1 is solved :-)

Is it now possible to calculate all 4 at once without getting the final results for each array individually?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you are trying to do. You can simplify your code in this way.

```js
function sum(arr) {
 return arr.reduce((acc, item) => acc += item[1], 0);
}

const result = sum(MyArray.M[0].GA.L) + sum(MyArray.M[0].GA.M) + sum(MyArray.M[0].GA.R) + sum(MyArray.M[0].GA.RW);
```

Comment: @ Elad  huge thanks.

As quickly as you helped, I now have exactly the 2 things I wanted to know.
You guys are just great

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of a use for [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). The `reduce` method loops through all the elements of an array, and uses an accumulator to carry a result through the operation.

```js
const someArray = [ /* any number of values */ ]
const sum = someArray.reduce( ( acc, val ) => ( acc + val )
```

You can take this a step further and write the callback as a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), and dump all of your arrays into a BIGGER array, and use `reduce` on THAT ONE too!

```js
const summation = ( acc, val ) => ( acc + val )
const sumOfSums = ( acc, val ) => ( acc + val.reduce( summation, 0 ) )

const arrayOfArrays= [
  MyArray.M[0].GA.L,
  MyArray.M[0].GA.M,
  MyArray.M[0].GA.R
  MyArray.M[0].GA.RW
]

const total = arrayOfArrays.reduce( sumOfSums, 0 )
console.log( `output: ${total}` )
```